# .NET Core Razor pages change pages to anonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a project with .NET Core 2.1 Razor Pages. It was built using the authentication option in the new project UI. So, when I type the URL and hit enter, the website opens the Microsoft login page, and I cannot see any page until I am signed in.

Now, I have a request to change the behavior of the authentication and I need to show the home page (`Index`) and other pages without the authentication process. So, I think I have to move the login page to a button and allow those pages to be accessible by anyone.

Can you please show me the right direction for this change?

I see that the `[AllowAnonymous]` directive is only for the controller (ASP.NET Core MVC), because it is not working in the Razor page, where the client and server code are combined in 2 files.

Also, I found a post talking about `Service.AddRazorPage` but I got an error showing that this method is for MVC, so I don't know if I have to continue with my research to work with this method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        // options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact");
        // options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Private");
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
        // options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Private/PublicPages");
    })
    // ...
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I already have this service: services.AddMvc(options =>
      {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                  .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                  .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
      })
      .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);    So, if I change that one by the new one, the site doesn't work. I will need to combine those 2 services?

Comment: If you want all pages to be anonymous - remove the auth filter setup.